# AngularJS Filter not filtering the data properly

Tags: angularjs

This is my JSON response got from webservice.

```
[{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Soap","scid":"1"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Powder","scid":"2"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Food","scid":"3"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Diapers","scid":"4"},{"cid":"1","scname":"Sugar","scid":"5"},{"cid":"1","scname":"Salt","scid":"6"},{"cid":"1","scname":"Jaggery","scid":"7"},{"cid":"2","scname":"Tea","scid":"8"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Tea","scid":"8"},{"cid":"2","scname":"Coffee","scid":"9"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Coffee","scid":"9"},{"cid":"3","scname":"Whole Spices","scid":"10"},{"cid":"3","scname":"Powdered Spices","scid":"11"},{"cid":"3","scname":"Pickles","scid":"12"},{"cid":"12","scname":"Pickles","scid":"12"},{"cid":"12","scname":"Sauces","scid":"13"},{"cid":"47","scname":"Sauces","scid":"13"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Shampoo","scid":"14"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Hair Oil","scid":"15"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Conditioner","scid":"16"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Mehendi","scid":"17"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Hair Gel","scid":"18"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Hair Colors & Dyes","scid":"19"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Hair Brush","scid":"20"},{"cid":"17","scname":"Rajor","scid":"21"},{"cid":"17","scname":"Blade","scid":"22"},{"cid":"17","scname":"Shaving Cream","scid":"23"},{"cid":"17","scname":"Shaving Foam","scid":"24"},{"cid":"17","scname":"Shaving Gel","scid":"26"},{"cid":"17","scname":"Shaving Brush","scid":"27"},{"cid":"3","scname":"Masala","scid":"28"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Ghee","scid":"29"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Dalda","scid":"30"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Mustard Oil","scid":"31"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Soyabean Oil","scid":"32"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Groundnut Oil","scid":"33"},{"cid":"7","scname":"Toothpaste","scid":"34"},{"cid":"20","scname":"Detergent Powder","scid":"35"},{"cid":"20","scname":"Detergent Bar","scid":"36"},{"cid":"39","scname":"Health Drinks","scid":"37"},{"cid":"5","scname":"Dry Fruits","scid":"38"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Wheat Atta","scid":"39"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Suji","scid":"40"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Maida","scid":"41"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Besan","scid":"42"},{"cid":"12","scname":"Soup","scid":"43"},{"cid":"34","scname":"Bathing Soap","scid":"44"},{"cid":"27","scname":"Namkeen/Mixture","scid":"45"},{"cid":"25","scname":"Glucose, Marie & Milk Biscuits","scid":"46"},{"cid":"27","scname":"Chips","scid":"47"},{"cid":"21","scname":"Shoe Polish","scid":"48"},{"cid":"10","scname":"Maggi","scid":"49"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Maggi","scid":"49"},{"cid":"10","scname":"Pazzta","scid":"50"},{"cid":"25","scname":"Popcorn","scid":"51"},{"cid":"8","scname":"Dals","scid":"52"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Oats","scid":"53"},{"cid":"6","scname":"Hair Removal","scid":"54"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Honey","scid":"55"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Jam","scid":"56"},{"cid":"19","scname":"Fast Items","scid":"57"},{"cid":"7","scname":"Tooth Brush","scid":"58"},{"cid":"23","scname":"Toilet Cleaning","scid":"59"},{"cid":"14","scname":"Floor Cleaning","scid":"61"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Oil","scid":"62"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Cream","scid":"63"},{"cid":"7","scname":"Mouthwash","scid":"64"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Buttermilk","scid":"65"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Butter","scid":"66"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Butter","scid":"66"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Milk","scid":"67"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Milk","scid":"67"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Fresh Cream","scid":"70"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Cheese","scid":"71"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Cheese","scid":"71"},{"cid":"8","scname":"Rice","scid":"72"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Shampoo","scid":"73"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Lotion","scid":"74"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Corn Flour","scid":"75"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Rice Flour","scid":"76"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Jawar Flour","scid":"77"},{"cid":"4","scname":"Cotton batti","scid":"79"},{"cid":"4","scname":"Hawan Samagri","scid":"80"},{"cid":"4","scname":"Coconut","scid":"81"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Olive oil","scid":"82"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Face Wash","scid":"83"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Fairness Cream","scid":"84"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Face Scrub","scid":"85"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Face Pack","scid":"86"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Cold Cream","scid":"87"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Lip Balm","scid":"88"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Kajal","scid":"89"},{"cid":"15","scname":"Moisturiser","scid":"92"},{"cid":"15","scname":"Handwash","scid":"93"},{"cid":"34","scname":"Shower Gel","scid":"94"},{"cid":"15","scname":"Gulab Jal","scid":"95"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Cornflakes","scid":"96"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Bread","scid":"97"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Rice Flakes (Poha)","scid":"98"},{"cid":"47","scname":"Broken Wheat (Daliya)","scid":"99"},{"cid":"47","scname":"Puffed Rice (Laiya)","scid":"100"},{"cid":"47","scname":"Sago (Sabudana)","scid":"101"},{"cid":"20","scname":"Liquid Detergent","scid":"102"},{"cid":"13","scname":"Liquid Dishwash","scid":"103"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Curd","scid":"106"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Curd","scid":"106"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Paneer & Tofu","scid":"107"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Paneer & Tofu","scid":"107"},{"cid":"47","scname":"Ready Mix","scid":"108"},{"cid":"6","scname":"Sanitary Protection","scid":"109"},{"cid":"10","scname":"Vermicelli","scid":"110"},{"cid":"10","scname":"Noodles","scid":"111"},{"cid":"39","scname":"Energy Drinks","scid":"112"},{"cid":"38","scname":"Soft Drinks","scid":"114"},{"cid":"42","scname":"Mineral Water","scid":"116"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Fruit Juices","scid":"120"},{"cid":"43","scname":"Fruit Juices","scid":"120"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Soda","scid":"122"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Instant Drink Mix","scid":"123"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Ice Tea","scid":"124"},{"cid":"25","scname":"Cookies","scid":"125"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Rice Bran Oil","scid":"126"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Sunflower Oil","scid":"127"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Sweets","scid":"128"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Condensed Milk","scid":"130"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Chocolate","scid":"131"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Bleach","scid":"132"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Massage Oil","scid":"134"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Bath","scid":"135"},{"cid":"36","scname":"Papad","scid":"136"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Face Masks","scid":"137"},{"cid":"23","scname":"Liquid Handwash","scid":"138"},{"cid":"47","scname":"Muesli","scid":"139"},{"cid":"23","scname":"Air Freshner","scid":"140"},{"cid":"14","scname":"Wipes","scid":"141"},{"cid":"14","scname":"Brooms","scid":"142"},{"cid":"23","scname":"Tissue Paper","scid":"143"},{"cid":"13","scname":"Dishwash Bar","scid":"144"},{"cid":"13","scname":"Scrub Pad","scid":"145"},{"cid":"33","scname":"Mens Deo","scid":"146"},{"cid":"33","scname":"Womens Deo","scid":"147"},{"cid":"33","scname":"Womens Perfumes","scid":"148"},{"cid":"33","scname":"Mens Perfumes","scid":"149"},{"cid":"33","scname":"Talcum Powder","scid":"150"},{"cid":"15","scname":"Body Lotion","scid":"151"},{"cid":"15","scname":"Foot Care","scid":"152"},{"cid":"25","scname":"Cream Biscuits","scid":"153"},{"cid":"25","scname":"Salty Biscuits","scid":"154"},{"cid":"8","scname":"Basmati Rice","scid":"155"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Poha","scid":"156"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Custard Powder","scid":"157"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Instant Mixes","scid":"158"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Makka Atta","scid":"159"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Bajra Atta","scid":"160"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Papad Atta","scid":"161"},{"cid":"2","scname":"Tea Bags","scid":"162"},{"cid":"39","scname":"Energy Powder","scid":"164"},{"cid":"35","scname":"Pain Relievers","scid":"165"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Palm Oil","scid":"175"},{"cid":"3","scname":"Cooking Paste","scid":"176"},{"cid":"21","scname":"Shoe Brush","scid":"177"}]
```

Trying to filter it using:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="y in SubCategories | filter:{'cid': 2}:true | orderBy:'scname'">
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a ng-href='#here' ng-click='GetProducts( y.scid )' >{{ y.scname }}</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But its showing some awkward result. For example after filtering for cid : 2, this is the result.

```
Body Lotion
Butter
Buttermilk
Cheese
Cookies
Cream Biscuits
Curd
Dry Fruits
Foot Care
Fresh Cream
Glucose, Marie & Milk Biscuits
Gulab Jal
Handwash
Milk
Moisturiser
Pain Relievers
Paneer & Tofu
Popcorn
Salty Biscuits
```

Expected:

```
Coffee
Tea
Tea Bags
```

Can please some1 help, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Why is Coffee, Tea and Tea Bags not in the results?

Comment: @Sam Good Observation. I cross checked. They are not in result. No Idea why.

Comment: Can you cross check if this is the correct Json you posted or are using? I don't see some subcategories having 2 at all in their cid value.

Comment: @Sam Yes this is correct JSON. Even i observed the same. I edited the question. Its showing some awkward result.

Comment: You are comparing `number 2` with `string` "2" in `cid`

Answer (score 2):

It's because in the JSON object, cid is having `string` as value `"2"`.

But you're passing `number` as input : `2`.

It should be

```
<tr ng-repeat="y in data | filter:{'cid': '2'}:true | orderBy:'scname'">
```

It will solve your problem :)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.data = [{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Soap","scid":"1"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Powder","scid":"2"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Food","scid":"3"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Diapers","scid":"4"},{"cid":"1","scname":"Sugar","scid":"5"},{"cid":"1","scname":"Salt","scid":"6"},{"cid":"1","scname":"Jaggery","scid":"7"},{"cid":"2","scname":"Tea","scid":"8"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Tea","scid":"8"},{"cid":"2","scname":"Coffee","scid":"9"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Coffee","scid":"9"},{"cid":"3","scname":"Whole Spices","scid":"10"},{"cid":"3","scname":"Powdered Spices","scid":"11"},{"cid":"3","scname":"Pickles","scid":"12"},{"cid":"12","scname":"Pickles","scid":"12"},{"cid":"12","scname":"Sauces","scid":"13"},{"cid":"47","scname":"Sauces","scid":"13"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Shampoo","scid":"14"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Hair Oil","scid":"15"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Conditioner","scid":"16"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Mehendi","scid":"17"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Hair Gel","scid":"18"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Hair Colors & Dyes","scid":"19"},{"cid":"16","scname":"Hair Brush","scid":"20"},{"cid":"17","scname":"Rajor","scid":"21"},{"cid":"17","scname":"Blade","scid":"22"},{"cid":"17","scname":"Shaving Cream","scid":"23"},{"cid":"17","scname":"Shaving Foam","scid":"24"},{"cid":"17","scname":"Shaving Gel","scid":"26"},{"cid":"17","scname":"Shaving Brush","scid":"27"},{"cid":"3","scname":"Masala","scid":"28"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Ghee","scid":"29"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Dalda","scid":"30"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Mustard Oil","scid":"31"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Soyabean Oil","scid":"32"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Groundnut Oil","scid":"33"},{"cid":"7","scname":"Toothpaste","scid":"34"},{"cid":"20","scname":"Detergent Powder","scid":"35"},{"cid":"20","scname":"Detergent Bar","scid":"36"},{"cid":"39","scname":"Health Drinks","scid":"37"},{"cid":"5","scname":"Dry Fruits","scid":"38"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Wheat Atta","scid":"39"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Suji","scid":"40"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Maida","scid":"41"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Besan","scid":"42"},{"cid":"12","scname":"Soup","scid":"43"},{"cid":"34","scname":"Bathing Soap","scid":"44"},{"cid":"27","scname":"Namkeen/Mixture","scid":"45"},{"cid":"25","scname":"Glucose, Marie & Milk Biscuits","scid":"46"},{"cid":"27","scname":"Chips","scid":"47"},{"cid":"21","scname":"Shoe Polish","scid":"48"},{"cid":"10","scname":"Maggi","scid":"49"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Maggi","scid":"49"},{"cid":"10","scname":"Pazzta","scid":"50"},{"cid":"25","scname":"Popcorn","scid":"51"},{"cid":"8","scname":"Dals","scid":"52"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Oats","scid":"53"},{"cid":"6","scname":"Hair Removal","scid":"54"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Honey","scid":"55"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Jam","scid":"56"},{"cid":"19","scname":"Fast Items","scid":"57"},{"cid":"7","scname":"Tooth Brush","scid":"58"},{"cid":"23","scname":"Toilet Cleaning","scid":"59"},{"cid":"14","scname":"Floor Cleaning","scid":"61"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Oil","scid":"62"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Cream","scid":"63"},{"cid":"7","scname":"Mouthwash","scid":"64"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Buttermilk","scid":"65"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Butter","scid":"66"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Butter","scid":"66"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Milk","scid":"67"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Milk","scid":"67"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Fresh Cream","scid":"70"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Cheese","scid":"71"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Cheese","scid":"71"},{"cid":"8","scname":"Rice","scid":"72"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Shampoo","scid":"73"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Lotion","scid":"74"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Corn Flour","scid":"75"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Rice Flour","scid":"76"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Jawar Flour","scid":"77"},{"cid":"4","scname":"Cotton batti","scid":"79"},{"cid":"4","scname":"Hawan Samagri","scid":"80"},{"cid":"4","scname":"Coconut","scid":"81"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Olive oil","scid":"82"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Face Wash","scid":"83"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Fairness Cream","scid":"84"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Face Scrub","scid":"85"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Face Pack","scid":"86"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Cold Cream","scid":"87"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Lip Balm","scid":"88"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Kajal","scid":"89"},{"cid":"15","scname":"Moisturiser","scid":"92"},{"cid":"15","scname":"Handwash","scid":"93"},{"cid":"34","scname":"Shower Gel","scid":"94"},{"cid":"15","scname":"Gulab Jal","scid":"95"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Cornflakes","scid":"96"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Bread","scid":"97"},{"cid":"18","scname":"Rice Flakes (Poha)","scid":"98"},{"cid":"47","scname":"Broken Wheat (Daliya)","scid":"99"},{"cid":"47","scname":"Puffed Rice (Laiya)","scid":"100"},{"cid":"47","scname":"Sago (Sabudana)","scid":"101"},{"cid":"20","scname":"Liquid Detergent","scid":"102"},{"cid":"13","scname":"Liquid Dishwash","scid":"103"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Curd","scid":"106"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Curd","scid":"106"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Paneer & Tofu","scid":"107"},{"cid":"45","scname":"Paneer & Tofu","scid":"107"},{"cid":"47","scname":"Ready Mix","scid":"108"},{"cid":"6","scname":"Sanitary Protection","scid":"109"},{"cid":"10","scname":"Vermicelli","scid":"110"},{"cid":"10","scname":"Noodles","scid":"111"},{"cid":"39","scname":"Energy Drinks","scid":"112"},{"cid":"38","scname":"Soft Drinks","scid":"114"},{"cid":"42","scname":"Mineral Water","scid":"116"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Fruit Juices","scid":"120"},{"cid":"43","scname":"Fruit Juices","scid":"120"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Soda","scid":"122"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Instant Drink Mix","scid":"123"},{"cid":"29","scname":"Ice Tea","scid":"124"},{"cid":"25","scname":"Cookies","scid":"125"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Rice Bran Oil","scid":"126"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Sunflower Oil","scid":"127"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Sweets","scid":"128"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Condensed Milk","scid":"130"},{"cid":"26","scname":"Chocolate","scid":"131"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Bleach","scid":"132"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Massage Oil","scid":"134"},{"cid":"41","scname":"Baby Bath","scid":"135"},{"cid":"36","scname":"Papad","scid":"136"},{"cid":"28","scname":"Face Masks","scid":"137"},{"cid":"23","scname":"Liquid Handwash","scid":"138"},{"cid":"47","scname":"Muesli","scid":"139"},{"cid":"23","scname":"Air Freshner","scid":"140"},{"cid":"14","scname":"Wipes","scid":"141"},{"cid":"14","scname":"Brooms","scid":"142"},{"cid":"23","scname":"Tissue Paper","scid":"143"},{"cid":"13","scname":"Dishwash Bar","scid":"144"},{"cid":"13","scname":"Scrub Pad","scid":"145"},{"cid":"33","scname":"Mens Deo","scid":"146"},{"cid":"33","scname":"Womens Deo","scid":"147"},{"cid":"33","scname":"Womens Perfumes","scid":"148"},{"cid":"33","scname":"Mens Perfumes","scid":"149"},{"cid":"33","scname":"Talcum Powder","scid":"150"},{"cid":"15","scname":"Body Lotion","scid":"151"},{"cid":"15","scname":"Foot Care","scid":"152"},{"cid":"25","scname":"Cream Biscuits","scid":"153"},{"cid":"25","scname":"Salty Biscuits","scid":"154"},{"cid":"8","scname":"Basmati Rice","scid":"155"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Poha","scid":"156"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Custard Powder","scid":"157"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Instant Mixes","scid":"158"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Makka Atta","scid":"159"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Bajra Atta","scid":"160"},{"cid":"9","scname":"Papad Atta","scid":"161"},{"cid":"2","scname":"Tea Bags","scid":"162"},{"cid":"39","scname":"Energy Powder","scid":"164"},{"cid":"35","scname":"Pain Relievers","scid":"165"},{"cid":"11","scname":"Palm Oil","scid":"175"},{"cid":"3","scname":"Cooking Paste","scid":"176"},{"cid":"21","scname":"Shoe Brush","scid":"177"}];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="y in data | filter:{'cid': '2'}:true | orderBy:'scname'">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a ng-href='#here' ng-click='GetProducts( y.scid )' >{{ y.scname }}</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my machine, this modification also giving the same result. I mean its not solving the problem  :(

Comment: Strange, it's working in my demo. Please setup a fiddle, we can look at it.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal I've added the demo here, you can try and let me know if  it works in your PC